# CSS :after conceptualization

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, pseudo-element

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/himmel/pen/BywrWj) that makes use of `:after` on an `<a>` element to create a nice hover effect. I forked a different codepen so that I could break it down into manageable, understandable parts, but I still am not entirely sure how the `:after` is used to create the effect here.

I know that `:after` is a <strike>pseudo-class</strike> pseudo-element that places another element after the one preceding the pseudo-element, but I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here.

Can someone help me understand how this works? Here is the relevant HTML and CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a class="underline animate">Hover me</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: #334D5C;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

.wrapper {
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

// basic styles for <a>
a.underline {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #E27A3F;
  position: relative;
}

// hover style for text only
a,a:visited,a:hover,a:active{
  transition:0.5s color ease;
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #45B29D;
  position: relative;
}

a.underline:after {
  left: 0;
}

// Animation styling
a.animate:after{
  bottom: 0em;
  height:5px;
  height:0.35rem;
  width:0;
  background-color: #45B29D;
  content: "";
  transition:0.5s width ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
          backface-visibility:hidden;
  position:absolute;
}

a.animate:hover:after{
  width:100%;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px);
 body {
  background-color: #334D5C;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
a.underline {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Slabo 27px';
  color: #E27A3F;
  position: relative;
}
a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  transition: 0.5s color ease;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #45B29D;
  position: relative;
}
a.underline:after {
  left: 0;
}
a.animate:after {
  bottom: 0em;
  height: 5px;
  height: 0.35rem;
  width: 0;
  background-color: #45B29D;
  content: "";
  transition: 0.5s width ease;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
a.animate:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
/*
a.underline:after {
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
          transform:translateX(-50%);
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="underline animate">Hover me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the codepen link now.

Comment: `::after` is a *pseudo-element*, not a *pseudo-class*.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Care to elaborate on how this works?

Comment: I would have, but [Jonas got there first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28304109/82548).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `after` is basically adding the underline thingy. It just adds an element at the bottom of the word and sets its width to 0. When you hover it, its width goes to 100%.
It also has a transition so you see it animated.
Here it is reduced to the bare bones:

```css
.element {
    position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.element::after {
content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: orange;
  -webkit-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
  transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
}

.element:hover::after {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  Something
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know that `:after` is a <strike>pseudo-class</strike> pseudo-element that places another element after the one preceding the pseudo-element, but I'm having trouble understanding what's going on here.

Actually, the `:after` pseudo-element is generated as a (last) child of the originating element, not as a following sibling. In other words, it's generated [after the *content* of the originating element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content), and not after the originating element itself. This serves to explain why

1. `position: relative` and `position: absolute` are able to work in conjunction to anchor the pseudo-element's position to the bottom of the `<a>` element, and
2. the width of the pseudo-element can be transitioned to 100% on hover, as this percentage is based on the width of the `<a>` element by virtue of being the pseudo-element's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a change on the main text which is basic: a color change on hover with an animation of 0.5sec.

The :after element is a kind of empty element which the content "" (empty) inside. The code tells the position (absolute and bottom: 0), the height (`height: 0.35rem;`), the `background-color: #45B29D;` and the `width : 0%;` that make the element invisible. On hover on a, the `width:100%`is set, again with an animation, so you'll see the underline expending

Comment: My apologies for the repeated edits; I was correcting (and re-correcting) the spelling mistakes; and then editing in your added content (the final sentence).